# EntityParameterCollection only accepts non-null EntityParameter type objects, not objects of type EntityParameter

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6

**Exception:**

> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: The
>   EntityParameterCollection only accepts non-null EntityParameter type
>   objects, not objects of type EntityParameter.

**Code:**

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{
    var cmd = db.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 LanguageString FROM Language AS L WHERE L.ID = @pLanguageID";

    var pli = new EntityParameter("pLanguageID", DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength);
    pli.Size = 3;
    pli.Value = languageID;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pli); // exception here
}
```

**Top of the stack trace:**

> [InvalidCastException: The EntityParameterCollection only accepts
>   non-null EntityParameter type objects, not objects of type
>   EntityParameter.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityParameterCollection.ValidateType(Object
>   value) +8069508
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityParameterCollection.Add(Object value)
>   +23

**Table info:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Language](
    [ID] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [LanguageString] [varchar](23) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Other info:**

I've tried a more general `EntityParameter` definition, but the same problem occurs. I only have read-only access to the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I've imported the wrong `EntityParameter`.

The correct namespace to import is `System.Data.EntityClient` it seems.

Comment: Ah seems I am also the same type of idiot. `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityParameter` is not the correct one. Whoops. To help google, the fully qualified correct one is `System.Data.EntityClient.EntityParameter`.